# any app to Stitch Video clips

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor

I have family video clips stored in different files & would like to stitch them onto one video(mp4)file for continued viewing.
Any recommended app? - preferred a simple one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OpenShot is pretty easy. Just open OpenShot, add your videos, and drag them around on the timeline until they are where you want them.

https://www.openshot.org/

Install it in the usual manner:

```
sudo apt install openshot
```